# how to distribute an array field in MySQL to rows

Tags: mysql

thanks for your answer but I don't know how to apply it very well to my case
my table name is (tblregs) please consider that I tried to apply the solution but I didn't succeed.

the SQL code that I applied:

```
select
  `Quan`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LinkedIDs, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) as name
from
  numbers inner join tblregs
  on CHAR_LENGTH(LinkedIDs)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(LinkedIDs, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
 Quan, n
```

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+------+
| LinkedIDs   | Quan |
+-------------+------+
| 150,151,152 | 50   |
+-------------+------+
| 200,250,270 | 35   |
+-------------+------+
| 151         | 80   |
+-------------+------+
| 260,152     | 90   |
+-------------+------+
```

what I tried to do is make it like the following table:

```
+-----------+------+
| LinkedIDs | Quan |
+-----------+------+
| 150       | 50   |
+-----------+------+
| 151       | 50   |
+-----------+------+
| 152       | 50   |
+-----------+------+
| 200       | 35   |
+-----------+------+
| 250       | 35   |
+-----------+------+
| 270       | 35   |
+-----------+------+
| 151       | 80   |
+-----------+------+
| 260       | 90   |
+-----------+------+
| 152       | 90   |
+-----------+------+
```

how to do that in MySQL?

note: the values in LinkedIDs can be 1 or more than one.

Comment: there are always 3 ids in the field LinkedIDs?

Comment: @BerndBuffen No, maybe 1 or more

Comment: FWIW, MySQL does not have array fields. You show a _string_, which happens to contain digits and commas.

Comment: This is messy to do in SQL; it would be better to do in your application language.  If you must use SQL, use a Stored Procedure, where you can "loop".